# How to unpack an array from php into Swift via JSON

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am retrieving an `Array` into Swift from PHP that contains the values from a couple of SQL queries.

The array is sent for, received and printed in Swift by following code:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
DispatchQueue.main.async
{

let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]

print (json)
}
```

The array contains `userDetails` and `Communities` and its output in Xcode (via printed debug) looks like the following:

```
Optional(["userDetails": {
id = 2;
"user_email" = "radowns82@gmail.com";
"user_name" = "<null>";
}, "communities": <__NSArrayI 0x60000002f500>(
{
name = Gallelio;
},
{
name = GallelioPart2;
}
)
])
Optional(["userDetails": {
id = 30;
"user_email" = "sam.bawdry@gmail.com";
"user_name" = "Samuel Bawdry";
}, "communities": <__NSArrayI 0x60800026e180>(
{
name = TesetTester;
},
{
name = Westbrook2;
},
{
name = WinnersOnly;
},
{
name = OneTwoThree;
},
{
name = WhoopdeWhoop;
}
)
])
```

How do I now unpack the contents of "communities" so I can display its contents in a `UITableVIew` - I have the `UITableView` already set up with and working with 'dummy data'.

This is the full Swift Script:

```
import UIKit

protocol UsernameSentDelegate {
func userLoggedIn(data: String)
}

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

var delegate: UsernameSentDelegate? = nil

@IBOutlet weak var userEmailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var displayUserName: UILabel!
var communitiesArray  = [String]()


@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject)
{

    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;

    if (userPassword!.isEmpty || userEmail!.isEmpty) { return; }

// send user data to server side


    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/userLogin.php");

    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);

    request.httpMethod = "POST";

    let postString = "email=\(userEmail!)&password=\(userPassword!)";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {


               if(error != nil)
                {

                    //Display an alert message
                    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error!.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
                    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    return
                }

                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]

                    if let arr = json?["communities"] as? [String:String] {
                    self.communitiesArray = arr.map { $0["name"] }
                }


                    // retrieve login details and check to see if all ok

                    if let parseJSON = json {

                        let returnValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String

                        if(returnValue != "error")
                        {

                            self.delegate?.userLoggedIn(data: userEmail! )

                            UserDefaults.set(UserDefaults.standard)(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");


                            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


                        } else {
                            // display an alert message
                            let userMessage = parseJSON["message"] as? String
                            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
                            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:nil)
                            myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                            self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }

                    }
                } catch
                {
                    print(error)
                }


        }



    }

    task.resume()


}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{

    if segue.identifier == "loginView" {
        let createViewController: ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
        createViewController.communities = communitiesBox
        print (communitiesBox)
    }


}



}
```

Comment: `if let communities = json["communities"] as Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> { //you have communities as Array and load it using table view methods... }`

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/120442/swift-json-tutorial i think its helpful for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can done that using two ways.

Declare one `Array` of type `[[String:String]]` and use that with your `TableView`.

```
var communitiesArray = [[String:String]]()

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
    if let arr = json["communities"] as? [[String:String]] {
        self.communitiesArray = arr
    }      
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Now in `tableView` method set use `communitiesArray` like `cell.label.text = self.communitiesArray[indexPath.row]["name"]`

If you are getting only `name` value with your `communities` then it is batter if you create just array of type `[String]` like this.

```
var communitiesArray = [String]()

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
    if let arr = json["communities"] as? [[String:String]] {
        self.communitiesArray = arr.flatMap { $0["name"]}
    }      
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Now in `tableView` method set use `communitiesArray` like `cell.label.text = self.communitiesArray[indexPath.row]`

Comment: I am getting error, "Type '(key: String, value: String)' has no subscript members.  On the line self.communitiesArray = arr.map...   It also forced me to put a ? in 'json?["communities"] - is that correct?

Comment: Excellent! There was a couple of additions xCode wanted to make (? after json, ! after ["name"] , but it looks to be working well! Cheers